# Clean file only if is not used by other processes

Tags: bash, concurrency, embedded-linux, busybox

I need to clean a file every x hours in order to clean RAM usage.
With BusyBox v1.23.2

So I can do this:

```
cat /dev/null > myfile.txt
```

This works correctly.
But, there are other processes that read this file and perform other actions, so how can I clean the file, and be sure that no other processes are reading/writing myfile.txt?

Pseudo code:

```
if(file_not_used()) ==> cat /dev/null > myfile.txt
```

I would like to do this with a bash script scheduled with crontabs.

Comment: Take a look at https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof

Comment: Better than `lsof` is  `fuser` -- identify processes using files or sockets. More info on `man fuser`

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using BusyBox v1.23.2, so I don't have lsof or fuser

Comment: @DDBE seems like `fuser` is part of it https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

Comment: @kvantour Thanks, I need to add it to the building process!